# Using replace on every label in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, each

I'm trying to do a replace on all the labels in my form when it loads in JS, but I'm having no luck.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.label').each(function(e){
        document.getElementById($(this)).textContent = document.getElementById($(this)).innerHTML.replace("and", "&");
    });
});
```

I don't know what's better: `.innerHTML` or `.textContent`. They seem to both achieve my goal.
Thanks in advance.

After Testing:
I really wish i could get the below code to work.

```
$('label').text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace("and", "&");
})
```

Thanks for everyone's suggestions, I have gotten the code to work with a simple loop.

```
var myElements = document.getElementsByTagName("LABEL");
for(var k=0; k<myElements.length; k++){
    myElements[k].innerHTML = myElements[k].innerHTML.replace("and", "&");
}
```

Comment: Since you are using jQuery you can do this: `$('.label').text(function(i, text) {return text.replace("and", "&"); })` !

Comment: Could you give a little more detail please? I like how clean it looks, but would i insert that into my `.each(function(e)){` simply throwing it in the `$(document).ready(function($){` doesnt work.

Comment: Please take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/59z31qm3/ it's a working example. I didn't post that as an answer because simply doesn't answer your question : **and idk whats better .innerHTML or .textContent**

Comment: I like the working example, its very clean but for some reason it messes up with other code. :(